# Call function in ASP.NET Master Page (.Master) from aspx.cs

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

In the ASP.NET Master Page (.Master) there is a text-box that should filter the content in a website. To do it I would like to call the function GetMessageLogs in the .aspx.cs file.

> Site.Master:

```
<button onclick="containCatText()" class="catbtn">Category</button>
    <div id="myDropdownCat" class="catdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myCat" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    </div>
    <script>
        var myCat = document.getElementById("myCat").value;
    </script>
```

> Feeds.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Feeds.aspx.cs" Inherits="ReportTool.Users.Feeds" %>
```

> Feeds.aspx.cs:

```
namespace ReportTool.Users
{
    public partial class Feeds : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Inov.ReportTool rt = new Inov.ReportTool();    
        MessageLogs = rt.GetMessageLogs(null, Server.MapPath("/ReportTool/Photo") + "\\", Server.MapPath("/ReportTool/Video") + "\\", new DateTime(2016, 09, 15),DateTime.Now, "%J%","Tr");
```

My question is simply how do I replace the "%J%" in the Feeds.aspx.cs from the variable myCat from Site.Maste?

Comment: hmm, first you will need a `postback` since the asp part cant see what your js side do - otherwise you are going UpdatePanel or AJAX. you can use find control on the master page i believe to access it from the `Feeds.aspx.cs` part.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: The following answer will demonstrate how to use the ASP.Net `UpdatePanel` and `FindControl` works. It just the basic.

First of all, change the textbox and the button into ASP Control so that the ASP can recognise them and bind them.

> Site.Master

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnFilter" Text="Category" CssClass="catbtn" />
    <div class="catdown-content">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtCategory">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

> Feeds.aspx

```
<%-- ScriptManager is mandatory for UpdatePanel --%>
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdPnlFeedWidget">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- In this example this label will change its content after the BtnFilter is clicked --%>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblContent">
        </asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <%-- Register the button that will trigger the UpdatePanel content --%>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnFilter" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

> Feeds.aspx.cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the TxtFilter that we want to get the value
        Control cntrlFilter = this.Master.FindControl("TxtCategory");
        if (cntrlFilter != null)
        {
            //Cast the Control instance to TextBox
            TextBox txtFilter = (TextBox)cntrlFilter;
            //Assign the content into the label
            LblContent.Text = txtFilter.Text;
        }
    }
```

The code will roughly goes like this: You clicked the `BtnFilter`, it then triggers the `UpdPnlFeedWidget` control and it will do an AJAX request, once the request received by the server the code will look for `TxtFilter's` value sent along with the request then set the `LblContent`, then it will return HTML that will replace the `UpdPnlFeedWidget` content. You can see the requests through Network tab on your Browser Console.

This approach is pretty common on ASP Web Form way of doing things. At least, for a while..